# Weird face problem

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and I don't know how to make a less curve face without generating triangles

[image: Weird face]

This is the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T-h16PACdFQqx3I-V6CRKoMI1OZIZ0Uh

Comment: what are you trying to make there? "less curve face" is not clear.

Comment: I want to make a 90° angle but the face is curve, even with loop cuts. I hope it's clear now, sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Can you show us a non-subdivided simple mesh that has the right shape, even if the topology is off? Otherwise we're just going to be guess here. Is this what you want? https://i.imgur.com/Fijd4jh.png

Comment: @Rekov 48 Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an edge where you want the sharp corner. You need an edge there before you can add supporting geometry to it. Here is a simplified version of the shape you're trying to achieve with the correct topology:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have three edges overlapping themselves.

Select the edges showed in the picture below and drag them to the left. You will notice what is happening.

[image]